# Remove Telerik Cache and Release Memory

Tags: asp.net, caching, telerik

The scenario:
I'm using Telerik Report Viewer in my web application to show large reports (about 5000 records from my DB, resulting in a 80 page document to display).
Everything was working just fine... but on this terrible day my app starts to throw a "Out of Memory" exception.

I realize that Telerik Report was caching all data and only releasing it after a long time(15 minutes or more).
The cache for one report consume at least 300mb!

The things is... I want to empty this cached data AND release my memory.
The memory consumpion persist even after I clear the cache using the following code:

```
HttpRuntime.Close()

//or

foreach (DictionaryEntry item in HttpContext.Current.Cache) {   
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove((string)item.Key);
}
```

Any ideias?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a warning, from my experience, Telerik questions tend to get (unfairly) downvoted here, sometimes with suggestions to contact support and formus

Comment: I don't know where you're getting your information, but checking the [telerik] tag shows lots of questions, none of which are downvoted (below 0 atleast) or closed...

Comment: And contacting their forums is last not least a good idea.
They know what they do in code behind and are therfore (from my point of view) the first address for requests related to their products.

Not to forget that telerik provides excellent support in their forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and dirty way I found to prevent this issue is to export the report (pdf, rtf...) and not display it on the page.